# Abnormal memory usage of MacOS bluetoothd and configd processes

Tags: bluetooth, memory, ventura

MacBook Pro M1 Pro 16+512G MacOS Ventura 13.6 As the boot time increases, the memory usage of bluetoothd and configd gradually increases. After a long period of sleep and restart, these two processes will also occupy a large amount of memory.

[image]

In my impression, this issue only appeared after updating MacOS 13.6. I recently installed AIDente to manage batteries, but I'm not sure if it's related to this

Comment: This is quite strange. Thanks for creating this question